# Which of these ECC libraries is more secure, fast and commonly used?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have a python project and for this project, I need to use Weierstrass-based [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm). On the web, I've found two libraries;

1. Library 1 is called [fastecdsa](https://fastecdsa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fastecdsa.html#module-fastecdsa.keys):
2. Library 2 is called [ECPy](https://cslashm.github.io/ECPy/index.html#ecpy.keys.ECPrivateKey.get_public_key%20.):

I couldn't see any security analysis and performance metrics for those libraries.

- Is there any security and performance analysis of these libraries?
- Is there a better alternative for those libraries?

Comment: Opinion based questions, library specific and programming questions are all off topic here unfortunately

Comment: The problem with "best" is that it depends on perspective: secure (and under what threat model: side-chanels)? fast (under what benchmark)? small? foolproof to use? easy to use? commonly used? easy to install? portable? open-source (per what license)? clear? extensible? cheap?

Comment: @fgrieu Yeah I should have precised the perspective I needed; "best" depending on which is more secure against side-channel attacks , easy and commonly use

Comment: @ChaiMa I took the liberty to update your question, please check. Note that python cannot go with side-channel security easily, except the python calls some C, C++ libraries, etc.

Comment: @kelalaka why can't python go with side channel security ?

Comment: In short, the constant time requires low level.

Comment: thank you @kelalaka